# Subscript to linear index

Tags: matlab

M is a matrix of prime numbers from 1 to 23 (in row order)

I don't understand how the second code line replaces the diagonal entries of M with 1. I am also confused because the function `sub2ind` converts row/column subscript to linear index both of which has nothing to do with the value of the entry.

```
M = zeros(3); M(:) = primes(23); M = M'
M(sub2ind(size(M), 1:3, 1:3)) = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`sub2ind(size(M), 1:3, 1:3)` returns an array `[1, 5, 9]` of the linear index of entries: `(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)`. In `M(sub2ind(size(M), 1:3, 1:3))` you are accessing `M` as a vector, it is equivalent to writing `M([1, 5, 9])` so you are accessing the matrix with linear indexing, and you are assigning the value 1 to those entries: `M(sub2ind(size(M), 1:3, 1:3)) = 1` so that changes the value of those entries